# I get an unknown error from React-native-google-signin

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-oauth

After following the setup guide from GitHub (for Android)
https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-google-signin

I'm able to the add the package and the signIn button successfully into my app, however, when I click it I get unknow error, check last else block on this code. *"some other error happened"*

```
_signIn = async () => {
  try {
    await GoogleSignin.hasPlayServices();
    const userInfo = await GoogleSignin.signIn();
    console.log('userInfo...');
    console.log(userInfo);
    this.setState({ userInfo });
  } catch (error) {
    if (error.code === statusCodes.SIGN_IN_CANCELLED) { 
      console.log('cancelled the login flow...');
    } else if (error.code === statusCodes.IN_PROGRESS) { 
      console.log('operation (f.e. sign in) is in progress already');
    } else if (error.code === statusCodes.PLAY_SERVICES_NOT_AVAILABLE) { 
      console.log('play services not available or outdated');
    } else { 
      console.log('some other error happened');
    }
  }
};
```

The button.

```
<View style={styles.container}>
        <GoogleSigninButton
        style={{ width: 192, height: 48 }}
        size={GoogleSigninButton.Size.Wide}
        color={GoogleSigninButton.Color.Dark}
        onPress={this._signIn}
        disabled={false} />
 </View>
```

Also if anyone can clarify the OAuth **webClientId**, which one should i use from firebase console since because i see both app and web, the set up mentions nothing about androidClientId.

```
GoogleSignin.configure({
    webClientId: 'xxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com', 
    GoogleService-Info.plist)
});
```

[image: 1]

Comment: I am getting WRONG SIGNIN Error: RNGoogleSignInError: Unknown error when signing in . Inside iOS google login